# Derivation of $p(\omega|X,Y) = \frac{p(Y|X, \omega) p(\omega)}{p(Y|X)}$ in bayesian modelling

Tags: self-study, bayesian

I am reading [this thesis](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/yarin/thesis/thesis.pdf) on Bayesian modelling explanation and there is a statement (section 2.1) there which I can't understand:

[image]

Here we have a regression problem, where $X$ are our inputs, $Y$ are outputs and $\omega$ are model parameters.

Why we have $p(\omega)$ instead of $p(\omega | X$)? If we apply Bayes rule to $p(\omega|X,Y)$ we get:

$$p(\omega|X,Y) = \frac{p(Y|X, \omega) p(\omega | X)}{p(Y|X)}$$

The only way to get the statement from the paper is to assume either $p(\omega | X) = p(\omega)$ or $p(X,Y) = p(Y|X)$, both of which feels wrong to me.

Comment: Why wouldn't it be that $w$ is independent of $X$ so $p(w|X)=p(w)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you read carefully the relevant section of the thesis of Yarin Gal, you will see that $\omega$ is a parameter that indexes the conditional distribution of $Y$ conditional on the covariates X. As for instance in the regression model $Y=X\omega_+\epsilon$. There is thus little reason for $\omega$ to depend on $X$. (Although Zellner's G-prior is a counterexample to this statement.)

Answer (score 0):

I think

$$P(w|X,Y)=\dfrac{P(X,Y|w)P(w)}{P(X,Y)}=\dfrac{P(Y|X,w)P(X|w)P(w)}{P(Y|X)P(X)}$$

I also think $X$ and $w$ are independent, so $$P(X)P(w)=P(X,w)=P(X|w)P(w) \iff P(X)=P(X|w)$$

And therefore

$$P(w|X,Y) = \dfrac{P(Y|X,w)P(w)}{P(Y|X)}$$

Why are $X$ and $w$ independent?  What form we expect $w$ to take $a\ priori$ is completely independent of the observed $X$.  Of course, the actual $w$ that we choose will depend on $X$, but **without knowing anything about the data** $w$ is independent of $X$.

Comment: I think that notion "*prior*" is a consequence of applying a Bayes theorem to $p(\omega | D)$: when data $D$ is regarded as a whole, we absolutely legally get a prior $p(\omega)$ in the formula. But in the setting above we can't say "Well, let's call $p(\omega | X)$ a prior, so we can remove $X$ from it"

Answer (score 0):

Your question is on the proper derivation of \begin{equation}
p(\omega|X,Y)=\frac{p(Y|X,\omega)p(\omega)}{p(Y|X)}
\end{equation}

Let me give you some intuition.  $\omega$ is the set of parameters that link $x\in{\mathbf{X}}$ to $y\in\mathbf{Y}$.  It does not depend upon the distribution of either $X$ or $Y$.

The $$p(Y|X,\omega)p(\omega)$$ could be written out as $$p(Y|X,\omega)p(X,\omega).$$  Because they are independent, $$p(X,\omega)=p(X)p(\omega).$$  There is no uncertainty regarding data in a Bayesian context so $p(X)=1$.  This leaves you with the prior probability of $\omega.$  For the denominator, because $\omega$ is marginalized out, you are left with $p(Y|X)$ because $$p(Y|X)=\int_{\omega\in\Omega}p(Y|X,\omega)p(\omega)\mathrm{d}\omega.$$

If you want to be really technical, you could make $p(X)=k,k\in(0,1]$ because it is independent of the rest of the denominator and would pass outside the integral and vanish through canceling for all values $\omega\in\Omega$.

Comment: I can't understand why $\omega$ does not depend on either $X$ or $Y$? If we'll draw a graphical model for them, how will it look like?

Comment: $\omega$ only describes the relationship between X and Y and says nothing about X or Y.  It doesn't say that X follows a Poisson distribution or that Y is a limited dependent variable.  X is the specific sample that was actually about to be seen.

Comment: @WunschPunsch if you don't mind passing into a slightly improper argument, imagine there was a time delay between X and Y.  This discussion doesn't actually depend on a delay, but it might be easier to see it.  Let's assume that X is a random variable and that we know the parameter $\omega$ exactly and it is the case that $\omega=2$.  So when X appears, three second laters Y=2X.  X does not depend upon the value 2.  Y depends on the 2 and X jointly, but X is not impacted by the transformation into Y.